# csv manipulation in bash/zsh, call date calculation function for field in each line

Tags: bash, date, zsh

I am manipulating a **csv** file in a shell script (using **zsh** on Ubuntu for Windows). In one field I have a **date** in format *DDMonYY* (eg 02Feb18). I am trying to replace the value of this field with the calculated date of the Monday of the parsed date's week.

For this I have written the following function:

```
function MondayOfWeekForDate {

    parsedDate=$1
    dayOfWeek=$(date -d "$parsedDate" +%u)
    removeDays=$(($dayOfWeek-1))
    monday=$(date -d "$parsedDate -$removeDays days" +%d%b%y)
    echo $monday

}
```

Because I am manipulating the whole file by fileds I tried using this function in awk but had no luck. I tried using:

- `system("MondayOfWeekForDate " $dateColumn)`
- `system("the above function written as a one liner to use directly date")`
- (Multiple forms of) `command | getline`

I ended up with a dirty workaround just to have something functional since I was in a hurry at the time, but it is seriously flawed in many ways (generally not code I'd be proud of). It's awfully written and performance is lame.

what I basically do is break my file in temporary files to isolate the column I need. Then using the file corresponding to my date column I do:

```
while read parsedDate; do
    MondayOfWeekForDate $parsedDate >> columnDateNew
done < columnDate
```

Then I just use paste to join my columns back together.

Obviously this is not a clever solution at all and also a very slow one (taking in mind the function calls and I/O s). Performance is actually terrible and it can take about 40 seconds to calculate the dates for 200 records. I am looking for a better solution, cleaner and with better performance.

Thanks in advance to anyone and everyone that will offer their insight. Also feel free to comment on any other part of my given code and/or solution, I'm always open to feedback.

Comment: Please add the awk code that didn't work since it could be a good way to go.

Comment: `command | getline nextMonDate` would be the proper form in `awk`. As above,  show us your best attempt to solve the problem so we can help. Good luck.

Comment: It's been over a week since I last tried this I believe but it should be along the lines of `MondayOfWeekForDate $4 | getline $4` where $4 is my dateColumn. I also tried `MondayOfWeekForDate $4 | getline otherVar`, and 
`date -d "$4 -$(date -d $4 +%u) days + 1 day" | getline var`. 
Similarly I tried that last one liner with system as in 
`system("date -d \"" $4 "-$(date -d " $4 "+%u) days + 1 day\"")`

Comment: arg, please don't require readers to wade thru an ever increasing thread just to understand what you have tried. Please move your code and comments to the body of your Q. Good luck.

Comment: you won't have access to a function declared in the shell from your awk program. Convert it to a script (or awk function) and call (if script) like `/path/to/MondayOfWeek inputVar | getline nextMonday`. Good luck.

Comment: GNU Awk has convenient time access function but they are not in POSIX Awk. Do you have `gawk` at your disposal? (Do you *really* need to be using Windows?)

Comment: Also, are the dates very sparse, or can you meaningfully pregenerate an array of Mondays for say 60 weeks back from now and take it from there?

Answer (score 4):

If gawk is available, try something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
    str = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec";
    for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            m2n[substr(str, i * 3 - 2, 3)] = i;
    }
    tzoffset = mktime(sprintf("%04d %02d %02d %02d %02d %02d",
            1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));

    day = "02Feb18";
    print MondayOfWeekForDate(day);
}

function MondayOfWeekForDate(day,
    removeDays, monday, yy, mm, dd, epoch, epochDays)
{
    yy = substr(day, 6, 2);
    mm = m2n[substr(day, 3, 3)];
    dd = substr(day, 1, 2);
    epoch = mktime(sprintf("%04d %02d %02d %02d %02d %02d",
            yy + 2000, mm, dd, 0, 0, 0));
    removeDays = (int((epoch -tzoffset)/ 86400) + 3) % 7;
            # +3 is because epoch started on Thursday
    monday = strftime("%d%b%y", epoch - removeDays * 86400);
    return monday;
}
```

The following is POSIX awk vesion, just in case:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    str = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec";
    for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        m2n[substr(str, i * 3 - 2, 3)] = i;
        n2m[i] = substr(str, i * 3 - 2, 3);
    }

    day = "02Feb18";
    print MondayOfWeekForDate(day);
}

function epoch2date(epochDays,
    u, v, w, x, y, year, mm, dd, mon)
{
    u = 719468 + epochDays;
    v = int(u / 146097);
    u -= v * 146097;
    if (u == 146096) {
        w = 3;
        u = 36524;
    } else {
        w = int(u / 36524);
        u -= w * 36524;
    }
    x = int(u / 1461);
    u -= x * 1461;
    if (u == 1460) {
        y = 3;
        u = 365;
    } else {
        y = int(u / 365);
        u -= y * 365;
    }

    year = 400 * v + 100 * w + 4 * x + y;
    mm = int((5 * u + 2) / 153) + 3;
    dd = u - int((153 * (mm - 3) + 2) / 5) + 1;
    if (mm > 12) { mm -= 12; year++; }

    year -= 2000;
    mon = n2m[mm];
    return sprintf("%02d%s%02d", dd, mon, year);
}

function epochdays(y, m, d,
    days)
{
    y += 2000;
    if (m < 3) { m += 12; y--; }
    days = 365 * y + int(y / 4) - int(y / 100) + int(y / 400) + int(306 * (m + 1) / 10) - 428 + d - 719163;
    return days;
}

function MondayOfWeekForDate(day,
    yy, mm, dd, epochDays, removeDays, monday)
{
    yy = substr(day, 6, 2);
    mm = m2n[substr(day, 3, 3)];
    dd = substr(day, 1, 2);

    epochDays = epochdays(yy, mm, dd);
    removeDays = (epochDays + 3) % 7;
    monday = epoch2date(epochDays - removeDays);
    return monday;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting the time into this!
Even though this is a complete answer, I was aiming for a bit more maintainable code. If 1 or 2 of those hardcoded numbers were changed even by mistake I'd be doomed. Let alone reading the code a year later :P


I actually ended up following @tripleee 's comment and pre-generated a file with all combinations as sedscripts. Then I can `sed -f sedFile targetFile` and the whole thing now runs in about 1/10th of the time it used to. I'll be updating the thread with my current solution.

Comment: Year, code maintainability is a very crucial issue and such an obfuscated codes as mine should not be mixed with active codes.  One possible solution would be to make use of `@include` statement of `igawk`.  Then you can encapsulate the untouchable codes as a library and minimize the risk of overwriting it.<br>
Anyway pre-generating a lookup table is a good idea because you can handle it as a separate file.  Good luck!